# Search Filter from json file data in React

Tags: json, reactjs, search, filter

I have built a search filter to React. The JSON file stores the name and the image of the model. There is an error like the name can be displayed on the website but the image is not read.
My code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/search-filter-in-reactjs-forked-k8nrf?file=/src/Search/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Input,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle
} from "mdbreact";

import "./style.css";
import modelList from "./models.json";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  renderModel = model => {

    return (
      <div className="col-md-3" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <p className="">
              <img
                src={model.image}
                className={model.image}
                alt={model.name}
              />
            </p>
            <CardTitle title={model.name}>
              {model.name.substring(0, 15)}
              {model.name.length > 15 && "..."}
            </CardTitle>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  };

  onchange = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    const filteredModels = modelList.filter(model => {
      return model.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });

    return (
      <div className="flyout">
        <main style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Input
                  label="Search Model"
                  icon="search"
                  onChange={this.onchange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col" />
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              {filteredModels.map(model => {
                return this.renderModel(model);
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Can someone stop by to help me display the image on JSON on the website? Thanks a lot

Comment: You have `src={blankImg}` when what you want is `src={model.image}`. Note that they are not going to resolve properly, better off having a public directory to store the images and load them from there

Comment: what do mean for the public directory?

Comment: can you have any examples for this?

Comment: from what I can tell, blanking does not appear to exist.
if i just made an <img src={blanking />  naturally, it creates nothing.

Comment: @AlexanderHemming I have updated the code, can not read the image on the website. how can I fix it?

Comment: @AlexanderHemming do you any suggestions to store image by json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the images to your public folder, so that they are not all loaded on startup but only if needed.

You can just move the whole folder like it is.

`<img src` will automatically search for images in the public folder, if you add a `/` in front of the url:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Sample 1",
    "image": "/asset/crab-nebuala.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sample 2",
    "image": "/asset/crab-nebula.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sample 3",
    "image": "/asset/ghost-nebua.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sample 4",
    "image": "/asset/sample-nebula-2.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sample 5",
    "image": "/asset/sample-nebula.png"
  }
]
```

That's all you need. Here is your updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-filter-in-reactjs-forked-x32ir?file=/src/Search/models.json:0-365).

Comment: the images display unorderly. how can rearrange the image inside a box?

Comment: Set a width and height e.g. 50 to the img component. If that solved your question, could you mark this as accepted so that others might find the answer too?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/search-filter-in-reactjs-forked-09r2r?file=/src/Search/models.json

Comment: What do you want to tell me with a link to the sandbox?

Comment: could you see the image display? can not fix, it is too big

Comment: As I said above, add a width and height to the img component. <img width={50} height={50} src={...} />

Comment: sorry for the reply late. It worked. Thanks a lot! @Domino987